# MySQL 10k tmp tables

Tags: mysql

I'm seeing `Created_tmp_disk_tables 10 k` within the PHPMyAdmin status screen and it's in red.  10k is an awful lot.  Is it my queries or server settings that are allowing temporary tables to get this high?  Is there any way to log queries that are creating temporary tables (please say yes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to know..

If an internal temporary table is created initially as an in-memory table but becomes too large..

MySQL automatically converts it to an on-disk table. The maximum size for in-memory temporary tables is the minimum of the **tmp_table_size** and **max_heap_table_size** values.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

BTW...
When the server creates an internal temporary table (either in memory or on disk), it increments the Created_tmp_tables status variable. If the server creates the table on disk (either initially or by converting an in-memory table) it increments the Created_tmp_disk_tables status variable.

What your seeing is an increment.. so when was the last time you restarted your mysql?? :D

Comment: It's been about 48 hours

Comment: Is there a way I can tell which queries are ending up on-disk?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

By using the slow-query-log, try to make anything longer than 1 sec fast.. By nature of disk tables.. they could be, and might be above 10seconds..

i have seen queries for 55 seconds from terrible keys and memory management

Comment: I ran the slow query check for like 6 hours and didn't see any in the logs, so I went back to logging queries without indexes.  I guess I might need more time?  Is it just long run queries that might end up on the disk?

Comment: Are you sure it was working?
i mean.. there is a good chance it wasnt running long enough..
I would restart your mysql server to reset the increment ( or do it manually )

and turn on slow query log at 1 second..

and wait..

You should see logs if that increment changes

Comment: Furthermore..
its possible that your max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size is soo small. that even 256kb sized queries are written to tmp disk..
(they might run under 1 second for example )

Check that too

Comment: `max_heap_table_size` is 128 MB and `tmp_table_size` is 512 MB.  I'll try running the long query check again

Comment: Ok great...

let me know how it goes.. Im sure we have diagnosed the problem..
Its just a matter of how you are using your queries..
Refer to my link about how mysql uses memory, to understand what type of queries ALWAYS go to disk

Comment: What I'm going to do is look into storing the results of some of the larger queries using `memcached` so hopefully this will go away.  I've reduced the number of temporary tables, but some of these queries just aren't going to get any better without some serious work.  Are the temporary tables cleared when they're finished?  I'm just concerned due to this high number...

Comment: Yes they are cleared..

Using memcache is a nice idea.. but somewhat more difficult to work with.. it might be worth it for caching static queries however..

Look into the queries which are large / or force disk temp tables and try to break them down..